# Multiple use of keyword "node" in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the follow code section:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[black] (a) {A};
   \node[black] (b) {B};
   \path (a) -- (b) node[blue, above];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

There are two uses of word "node": one with backslash and another without. Are these two usage related?

Comment: `\node` is shorthand for `\path node`.

Comment: And TikZ defines a number of such shorthand commands. `\draw` means `\path [draw]`, etc. TikZ has really good documentation, OP should check it out (not trying to be snarky).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes they are related … In general every thing in TikZ is a path with different *things* on it. The basic command to create a path is `\path`. If you need some text you create a path and add a node, like in

```
\path node {Text};
```

Since theres no explicit coordinate the default (0,0) is used.

Other examples are drawing or filling paths which can be done with

```
\path [draw] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
\path [fill] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
\path [fill,draw] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
```

And because such constructions are often needed there are shortcuts like

```
\node
\draw
\fill
\filldraw
```

and some more. All of them create a path (using `\path`) and apply the desired *thing* (draw, fill, text, …).